# My computed property is not re-evaluating based on its reactive dependencies. It on re-evaluates when a method is ran and the page reloads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this computed property.

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('user/requestAcc', ['AccountValidation', 'selectedWorkload','AccountOnboarding','Regions','customers']),
    validatedForSubmission() {
      if(this.type !== 'Internal'){
         if (this.AccountValidation.wbsType === 'WBSCode1') {
            if(this.type !== 'New'){
              return !this.AccountValidation.agreed || !this.AccountValidation.wbsCodeValidated || !this.AccountValidation.iwoCodeValidated
            } else {
              return !this.AccountValidation.agreed || !this.AccountValidation.wbsCodeValidated 
              || !this.awsAccountValidation.iwoCodeValidated || !this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Tmp_Cust_Name ||!this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Cust_Region || !this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias ||  this.errors.items.length
            }
          } else {
            if(this.type !== 'New'){
              return !this.AccountValidation.agreed || !this.AccountValidation.wbsCodeValidated
            } else {
              return !this.AccountValidation.agreed || !this.AccountValidation.wbsCodeValidated 
              || this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Tmp_Cust_Name === '' ||!this. AccountOnboarding.fields.Cust_Region || !this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias ||  this.errors.items.length
            }
            
          }
        } else {
           if (this.AccountValidation.wbsType === 'WBSCode1') {
             return !this.AccountValidation.wbsCodeValidated || !this.AccountValidation.iwoCodeValidated
           } else {
              return !this.AccountValidation.wbsCodeValidated 
           }
        }
      }
  }
```

The computed property is linked to :disabled in a v-btn. So if the computed property returns a false value, it would enable(remove disabled) the v-btn.

```
 <v-btn :disabled='validatedForSubmission' color="warning"   @click='onAcctValidationSubmit'>Next</v-btn>
```

I connected one of the object properties from AccountOnboarding in a v-text-field. This is a reactive dependency in the *validatedForSubmission* computed property.

```
 <v-text-field
              placeholder="Customer_Alias"
              :counter="15"
              v-model="AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias"
              v-validate="'required'"
              data-vv-name="Customer Alias"
              :error-messages="errors.collect('Customer Alias')"
               outlined
            dense
            >
</v-text-field>
```

I have method linked to a v-autocomplete. This method checks if there is an existing Customer Registration.

```
 methods: {
    getCustomerRegion() {
      let custAlias = this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias
      let custName = this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Tmp_Cust_Name
      let custReg =  this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Cust_Region
      let isCustRegExist =  this.customers.filter(res =>  res.Cust_Region.includes(custName+' - '+custReg))
      if(isCustRegExist.length > 0) {
      this.AccountOnboarding.isCustRegion = true
      let alias = isCustRegExist[0].Customer_Alias
      this.AccountOnboarding.fields.MP_ID = isCustRegExist[0].Master_Id
        console.log('1. -------- selected customer --------')
        console.log('2. alias: ' + alias)
        console.log('3. -----------------------------------')
        if (alias !== 'None'){
            this.AccountOnboarding.custRegion =''
            this.AccountOnboarding.custRegionId= isCustRegExist[0].Customer_Id
            this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias = isCustRegExist[0].Customer_Alias
            this.$store.commit('user/requestAcc/setCustomerAlias', alias)
        }  else {
            console.log('customer update...')
            this.AccountOnboarding.custRegionAction = 'update'
            this.AccountOnboarding.custRegionId = isCustRegExist[0].Customer_Id
            this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias =''
            this.$store.commit('user/requestAcc/setCustomerAlias', this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias)
          } 
      } else {
              console.log('customer create...')
              this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias ='' 
              this.AccountOnboarding.custRegionAction = 'post'
              this.AccountOnboarding.isCustRegion = false
              this.AccountOnboarding.custRegionId = ''
              let alias = this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias
              this.$store.commit('user/requestAcc/setCustomerAlias', alias)
            }
    }
```

```
 <v-autocomplete
              v-model="AccountOnboarding.fields.Cust_Region"
              :items="Regions"
              placeholder="Select Customer Region"
              v-validate="'required'"
              data-vv-name="Customer Region" 
              data-vv-validate-on="blur"
              :error-messages="errors.collect('Customer Region')"
              @change = "getCustomerRegion"
              attach
              outlined
              dense
            >
            </v-autocomplete>
```

The computed property works fine and enables the button when there is an existing customer registration and it has a customer alias (which fills up the v-text-field). However, for new registrations or existing customers with no alias, you can see that the method would set *this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias ='' * and once you type in an alias in the v-text-field where you linked the AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias as a v-model, it does show that the AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias contains the inputted value but the computed property does not recalculate it even though it is a reactive dependency. Leading to the computed property to return false even if the conditions are met.

I have tried removing the code this.AccountOnboarding.fields.Customer_Alias ='' for both customer update and customer create conditions in the getCustomerRegion method, it worked but I do not want to remove the code.

Comment: Are you so sure the problem is with reactivity, and not with the condition? I would start by rewriting that

Comment: @MoritzRingler yes I have tried editing the condition under the computed property to where it returns a false or a true but it does not recompute unless a method is run (such as a checkbox is toggled to checked/unchecked) to reload the page. It is then only will it recompute the computed property condition.